# The number of real solutions of complicated surd

Tags: real-numbers

I have tried to solve this question, and I found the one real root, x=0, but I do not understand how to show that there is only one root:
Find the number of real solutions of $x+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^3+1}}=1$
The solution to the question, is 1 real solution, but I am not sure how to prove that there are no other solutions.

Comment: You solve the equation by squaring twice, remembering that this may introduce extraneous solutions. You will find two real solutions, but one will be extraneous, leaving only one solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the real square root to be defined $\,\sqrt{x^3+1}\,$, it is necessary that $\,x^3+1 \ge 0 \iff x \ge -1\,$. For $\,\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^3+1}}=1-x \ge 0\,$, it is necessary that $\,x \le 1\,$, so any real solution is in $\,[-1,1]\,$.

Eliminating the radicals:

$$
x^3+1 = \left((1-x)^2-x^2\right)^2 \;\;\iff\;\; x^3 - 4 x^2 + 4 x = 0 \;\;\iff\;\; x(x-2)^2=0
$$

The latter has the unique real solution  $\,x=0\,$ in $\,[-1,1]\,$.